# project.json warning in vscode when not using project.json

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I'm getting the following warning when using vscode

> Warning: project.json is no longer a supported project format for .NET
>   Core applications. Update to the latest version of .NET Core
>   (https://aka.ms/netcoredownload) and use 'dotnet migrate' to upgrade
>   your project (see https://aka.ms/netcoremigrate for details).

Thing is I'm not using project.json, I don't have one. I'm using a csproj. I migrated ages ago. There isn't a project.json anywhere in my folder structure.

You can see my code here: https://github.com/trampster/Jsonics

How do I get vscode to stop generating this warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a Jsonics/backup folder that contains two project.json files in your source code, you have to delete that folder or at least the project.json files within it.

Comment: Oh I feel stupid now, I removed the backup folder and it worked. Not even sure why I had a backup folder.

Comment: Ha, it happens, to all of us :)